# How to get the selected id of the div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have three divs like that:

```
<div id="1" >id="1"</div>
<div id="2">id="2"</div>
<div id="3">id="3"</div>
```

Now i want, when i click any of the div, jquery will get it id, i.e, if i click div 1, it will get 1 as its div id is 1.

any help will be great.

regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
});
```

or shorter:

```
$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() { alert(this.id); });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div").click(function() {
    var eleId = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use delegation or assign a click-handler to each of the divs:

```
$('#1, #2, #3').click(
   function (e) {
      alert($(this).attr('id') + ' was clicked');
   }
)
```

If you have a parent container you could use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)-method to bind a single listener and utilize event delegation:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="1" >id="1"</div>
   <div id="2">id="2"</div>
   <div id="3">id="3"</div>
</div>

$('#parent > div').live('click', function (e) {
   alert($(this).attr('id') + ' was clicked');
});
```